# Variable Width Outline Effect Around a Texture in 2D

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader, pixel-shader

I am looking to create a glsl shader program that will give me a variable width outline around an arbitrary 2d texture as shown in the picture. Is this a reasonable job for the GPU? I've looked at edge-detection approaches but those would only reasonably provide a few pixels border. I want arbitrary width. Is this doable?

[image]

Comment: Well in fragment shader you can `texelFetch` in say 8 directions of specified width around your current pixel, and if any texel has non-transparent alpha, then you return the red pixel. Though it sounds costly and the edge won't be as smooth

Comment: Yikes that's not encouraging. Maybe i'm barking up the wrong tree

Comment: @Bret: can you preprocess the texture? If yes then compute a SDF (signed distance field) and store it in the alpha channel. Look up text rendering with SDFs for inspiration.

Comment: Thanks I’ll read up on sdf. I was also considering a multi pass approach—drawing edge pixels on each pass so there would be a pass for each increase in line thickness.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_morphology#Dilation

Answer (score -1):

One approach would be to render the object to a texture with a bit larger scale and color it all the way your outline color should be.
Then you render it to another texture as it should be displayed.
In a third render pass you could then combine the 2 textures by choosing the outline texture, when the color-texture is empty and else the color texture.
This could be an expensive process, but it obviously depends on the scope of your project if that impacts performance too much.
[image: Image of three-Step image process]